# how to get maximum length of this function socket_recv() in PHP

Tags: php, sockets

```
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 2045, MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);        
    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg <br>");
}
echo $buf;
```

from the function above it doesn't show full message, so I tried to get the maximum length of variable $buf like this

> socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , strlen($buf), MSG_WAITALL )

but not work. please kindly help me

thx and regards,

Comment: Wich is the size in bytes of the data you're expecting to receive?  The first step here is to look into the protocol specification to know that.

Comment: `strlen()` doesn't get the maximum size of `$buf`, it gets the size of the data that's currently in `$buf`. What kind of socket is this, stream or datagram?

Comment: @Barmar stream 
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)

Comment: You need to call `socket_recv()` in a loop until you get everything. Unless the application protocol specifies a particular message size, it can be any length.

Comment: @Barmar It can be any length anyway, from 1 to the buffer size. It's a byte stream protocol, not a message protocol. Application message size has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Some applications may send fixed-size data. In that case, you make the buffer big enough to hold it, pass the size as the bufsiz argument, and MSG_WAITALL will wait until you receive that much. However, few protocols work like this.

Answer (score 4):

you should receive the response with a loop

```
$received;
while(socket_recv($sock, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
{
    $received .= $buf;
}
```