# socket_recv not receiving full data

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I'm sending from browser through Websocket an image data of around 5000 bytes but this line is receiving total of 1394 bytes only:

```
while ($bytes = socket_recv($socket, $r_data, 4000, MSG_DONTWAIT)) {
    $data .= $r_data;
}
```

This is after handshake is done which is correctly being received. The json data is being cutoff after 1394 bytes. **What could be the reason?**

In the browser interface it is sending image as JSON:

```
websocket.send(JSON.stringify(request));
```

The browser interface is fine as it is working with other PHP websocket free programs I've tested.

Here is the full [source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aEugGV1GwTZDRremE4MXlOMTQ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Well, a good start to figuring out what's wrong would be to stop ignoring any errors `socket_recv` may be giving. That error information might actually be useful. By using the [error suppression operator](http://php.net/language.operators.errorcontrol), you're throwing all of that potentially useful error information away. I would start with that before trying to make random guesses about what could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that no gzip encoding happens?

Comment: yes the data is cut off  the straightway

Comment: @user5858 What do you mean?

Comment: This reading only 1394 bytes out of around 5000 sent

Comment: Anyhow, MrZebra's answer is correct. Have you tried that?

Comment: It looks like your mixing raw TCP/IP with websockets. Did you send any data to the browser? it could be that the data you sent wasn't framed using the Websocket protocol - which would cause the connection to close. In fact, it could be that the 1394 bytes are the Websocket connection request, if you have some cookie data... (did you complete the handshake?)

Comment: Read my comments and/or have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12492723/694576

Comment: @user5858 Can you provide us with the image you are sending? Or is this behaviour consistent with all images you are sending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have our socket set up as non-blocking by specifying MSG_DONTWAIT, so it will return EAGAIN after it reads the first chunk of data, rather than waiting for more data.  Remove the MSG_DONTWAIT flag and use MSG_WAITALL instead, so that it waits for all the data to be received.

There are a few ways of knowing if you have received all the data you are expecting:

1. Send the length of the data.  This is useful if you want to send multiple blocks of variable length content.  For example if I want to send three strings, I might first send a "3" to tell the receiver how many string to expect, then for each one I would send the length of the string, followed by the string data.
2. Use fixed length messages.  If you are expecting multiple messages but each one is the same size, then you can just read from the socket until you have at least that many bytes and then process the message.  Note that you may receive more than one message (including partial messages) in a single recv() call.
3. Close the connection.  If you are sending only one message, then you can half-close the connection.  This works because TCP connections maintain separate states for sending and receiving, so the server and close the sending connection yet leave the receiving one open for the client's reply.  In this case, the server sends all its data to the client and then calls [socket_shutdown(1)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-shutdown.php)

1 and 2 are useful if you want to process the data while receiving it - for example if you are writing a game, chat application, or something else where the socket stays open and multiple messages are passed back and forth.  #3 is the easiest one, and is useful when you just want to receive all the data in one go, for example a file download.

Comment: It will only set `EAGAIN` if no data had been received at all, Otherwise the call will return the number of bytes received, which might be less then it was told to, even on a non-blocking socket.

Comment: Sorry, if I keep the loop on ... after plenty of EAGAINS it indeed is reading more of data after some time(after a few loop iterations). You have been right. But then how the server can know if complete payload data has been received and not even a byte is remaining?

Comment: Hi, please see my edit about how to know when you have received the data.  There are a few options depending on your needs.

Answer (score 7):

1394 is around the common size of an MTU, especially if you are tunnelled through a VPN (are you?).

You can't expect to read all the bytes in one call, the packets may be fragmented according to the network MTU.

Comment: No. I'm not using any VPN or proxy.

Comment: @user5858: The correct fact the answer describes covers any kind of transmission using TCP sockets. In PHP this applies at least to `socket_recv()` which wraps the system call `revc()`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html The data may as well be fragmented into pieces of any size up to 1 byte.

Answer (score 6):

Just my 2 cents on this. 
socket_recv can return false on an error. Where it can also receive zero (0) bytes in non-blocking IO.

Your check in your loop should be:

```
while(($bytes = socket_recv($resource, $r_data, 4000, MSG_DONTWAIT)) !== false) {}
```

Altough I would check the socket for errors also and add some usleep call to prevent "CPU burn".

```
$data = '';
$done = false;
while(!$done) {
    socket_clear_error($resource);
    $bytes = @socket_recv($resource, $r_data, 4000, MSG_DONTWAIT);

    $lastError = socket_last_error($resource);

    if ($lastError != 11 && $lastError > 0) {
        // something went wrong! do something
        $done = true;
    }
    else if ($bytes === false) {
        // something went wrong also! do something else
        $done = true;
    }
    else if (intval($bytes) > 0) {
        $data .= $r_data;
    }
    else {
        usleep(2000); // prevent "CPU burn"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you are having issues with your websockets connection. The while-loop you quote above looks to me to reside in a part of the code where the client handshake has failed, it's in the `else` of `if($client->getHandshake()) { ... } else { ... }`.

As far as I can tell the $client is a separate class, so I can't see what the class looks like or what Client::getHandshake() does, but I'm guessing it is the getter of a boolean that holds the success or failure of the websocket upgrade handshake.

If I'm correct the handshake fails and the connection is closed by the client. From the code I can see that the server-code you are using requires version 13 of the spec. You do no mention which client-side library you are using, but other servers will accept other versions than this server.

Please make sure your client-library supports the latest version.

Posting the verbose output from the server when it gets an incoming connection and the transfer fails will be of help if what I'm suggesting is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

BUT, isn't the portion of the code that you pasted contained in the else block? The else block that to me looks like the hand shake did not go through?

Could you print the received bytes as string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question is correct. According to the source code, if the handshake has succeeded then this section of code is executed:

```
$data = '';

while (true) {
    $ret = socket_recv($socket, $r_data, 4000, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if ($ret === false) {
        $this->console("$myidentity socket_recv error");
        exit(0);
    }
    $data .= $r_data;
    if (strlen($data) > 4000) {
        print "breaking as data len is more than 4000\n";
        break;
    } else {
        print "curr datalen=" . strlen($data) . "\n";
    }
}
```

If the program really goes to the code section that you provided then it will be worth to look into why the handshake failed.

The Server Class has a third parameter `verboseMode` which when set to true will provide you with detailed debug logs on what exactly is happening.

We will just be speculating without the debug log, but if the debug log is provided we can come up with a better suggestion.